# How to parse object from string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, kafka-consumer-api

Client is recieving events from Kafka server as a string , is it possible to get Json object from string ? Like in below data i wanted to parse `[object object]` from string or i should ask data Source to send parsed object ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];
$scope.event.push = data;
```

data

`[2017-03-22T20:40:03Z]|zl75848|info|id: c37a6657-2f97-4955-8756-09d94beacdba|actor.CIS|ENTITYID_1:1490215203745:[object Object]`

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Comment: there might be case when object will be already parsed in event i think it will throw error on `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: a json object should contain key and value, the data you shared,I'm not sure if there is a key present for the values.. some of them might have it, but unclear